# Doubts in Function defined as the integer inputs

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What the following definition represents about the function:

$f(1+\frac{1}{n})=1$ for all integers $n$.

I thought of substituting some integers to see what this function is doing. It turns out that function takes value $1$ at $0$ and $1$ Also, for other integers, say $n=2$, the function takes value $1$ at $x=\frac{3}{2}$. Looks like this is a constant Function but then book says that this is a non constant three times differentiable function. I am not able to understand what this function will look like? Any help in understanding the nature of this function will be great. Thanks in advance.

EDIT.1 The function is defined for $R\rightarrow R$ and is non constant and three times differentiable. I am required to obtain $f''(1)$

Comment: The [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function) satisfies this, for example, and it's certainly neither constant nor differentiable. Is your question missing some other conditions, maybe?

Comment: The question only says that this function is defined from $R\rightarrow R$ and is non constant and three times differentiable.

Comment: The question is asking for $f''(1)$

Comment: Please edit all that into the question itself, not as a comment.

Comment: With these data, I'm not sure you can fully characterize the function. For example, think in the function $$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 0, & x\leq 0 \\ e^{-1/x} , & x> 0 \end{array} \right. .$$ Certainly, this function is non-constant, and is also $C^\infty$. But $f\left(-1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$ for all integers. You know what I mean? Maybe your function is cnstant around $1$. But what happens at $x=7$?. What is the book? Probably it helps other people.

Comment: Also see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563776/let-fr-rightarrow-r-be-a-non-constant-three-times-differentiable-function-i?rq=1